# "Nier" utilise-t-il le subjonctif dans des phrases positives et négatives?

Tags: subjonctif, ne-explétif

D'après [ce site](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/subjunctivisor/nier/), le double négatif utilise également le subjonctif. Est-ce une erreur?

> When nier is in the negative, it's followed by the ne explétif:
>
> Il n'a pas nié qu'elle ne soit partie.    He didn't deny that she
> left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Nier* est [dans la littérature](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nie+qu'il+soit+%2B+nie+qu'elle+soit%2Cnie+qu'il+est+%2B+nie+qu'elle+est&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3) presque exclusivement suivi du subjonctif, pour l'affirmative aussi bien que pour la négative. Les seules exceptions que l'on trouve dans cette liste sont des constructions particulières comme *c'est à tort qu'il a nié que*…, *personne ne nie que*….

L'article parle d'un *ne* explétif après *ne pas nier*, qui, il y a deux siècles de cela, était prôné par le [*Dictionnaire raisonné des difficultés grammaticales et littéraires*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=OZUPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA537&dq="ne+nie+pas+qu'il"&hl=en), alors que l'académie acceptait déjà les deux formes à la même époque, mais depuis [environ 1930](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nie+pas+qu'il+ne+puisse+%2B+nie+pas+qu'elle+ne+puisse+%2B+nie+pas+qu'il+n'existe+%2B+nie+pas+qu'il+n'ait+%2B+nie+pas+qu'elle+n'ait%2Cnie+pas+qu'elle+puisse+%2B+nie+pas+qu'il+puisse+%2B+nie+pas+qu'il+existe+%2B+nie+pas+qu'il+ait+%2B+nie+pas+qu'elle+ait&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3) c'est à l'inverse devenu l'exception de trouver un *ne* explétif à cet endroit, bien que ça se trouve encore occasionnellement.

[L'article à ce sujet de Girodet](https://books.google.fr/books?id=KOINHRkfU_oC&pg=PA629&dq=nier+ne+expl%C3%A9tif&hl=en) confirme l'évolution et contient d'autres exemples intéressants.